# CSS - Align content area next to the sidebar without adding extra margin & javascript

Tags: html, css

there's a dummy example of how my sidebar & content area are aligned:

http://jsfiddle.net/rWj95/11/

As you see, I add the amount of the width that `#sidebar` contains to the content area, so the sidebar won't overlap the area of the content. It overlaps the content because `#sidebar` has `position: fixed;` property set.

Today, I wanted to add a button which I can resize my sidebar, and it became a problem because I have to change the margin amount of the content area every time I resize my sidebar.

I there an automatic way to align sidebar with content area?

Comment: You are going to resize your sidebar with jQuery? Why don't you show what you're attempting in full. Generally if you toggle something you can toggle the body or html class and then when the class is toggled adjust the margin on anything on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possibility is by wrapping the content in another div. You have your sidebar fixed to the left, and then a container/wrapper div around the rest of the body content, and write left:200px; only once...

however, it's always a good idea also to use percentages. Using percentages you can better monitor the structures of your page, and then to limit its dimensions you can start by giving it a max, min, or a set width. inner elements that you use 100% on will fill up to 100% of its container's width.

hope this is what you mean!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8C7U7/

add some containers like this within the content id:

```
        <article id="stuff">
            <p>buhreg</p>
        </article>
```

with the style:

```
#stuff{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:blue;
}
```

ps. try resizing the preview window!